# OutOfMemoryException в GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+

Время от времени ловлю `OutOfMemoryException` при вызове этого метода:
[Bitmap.Clone (Rectangle, PixelFormat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms141944(v=vs.110).aspx), хотя памяти у меня много.

Мне кажется, что проблема в `Rectangle`. Каким требованиям он должен соответствовать при вызове этого метода?

Comment: «хотя памяти у меня много» — физической или виртуального адресного пространства?

Comment: Физическая. Вроде, гугл говорит, что GDI на каждый чих кидает такое исключение

Comment: Единственно, что там сказано в документации: _rect выходит за пределы границы исходного растрового изображения_. А вообще, при работе с GDI+ очень часты исключения при неправильном указании PixelFormat. Постоянно напарывался.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да. Похоже на правду. Потестил с rect, который больше исходно изображения и словил ошибку.